# Wifi not working on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

hello I am on a brand new install of Ubuntu 15.04 on a lenovo b575 laptop everything is working but I can not enable the wifi. when I run the command "rfkill list all" everything listed says no except for "1: phy0: Wireless LAN" hard blocked says yes but my wifi switch is in the on position and the command "rfkill unblock all" does not work. I am not sure what to do from here, I would really appreciate it if someone would take the time to help.

Comment: I promise I'm not trolling, but did you check the bios entry, the front edge switch, and if there is an fn+key combo, pressing that?  I fought with a similar model once where I missed one of these spots.

Comment: No worries I know that you are not trolling. I have  all of those but it still says that I am hard blocked.

Comment: I just noticed that the wifi indicator light on the front of my laptop wont light up. does that mean that it is a hardware problem? If so does any know how to fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add FULL output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem by opening up my laptop disconnecting the wifi card. Then I started up the laptop with out the wifi card. After this I turned the laptop off and reconnected the wifi card. Now the command "rfkill list all" lists everything no and I am able to connect to my wifi again.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked up your Lenovo b575. Please make sure the PHYSICAL wifi switch on the front of the laptop is enabled.  Two thirds of the time when I am asked to help with wifi issues, it is that the user inadvertently turned off their laptop's physical wifi switch.

Comment: the wifi switch on the front of the laptop is in the on position but it is still saying that I am hard blocked.